# How to get hash output with single quotes in yaml format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I have a hash:

```rb
 copy_propetries =  {
   "command" => 'copy-item -Recurse -Path z:\*.txt c:\windows\temp',         
 }
                 
 puts copy_propetries.to_yaml
 Ouptut--  command: `copy-item -Recurse -Path z:\*.txt c:\windows\temp`
```

How can I get the output with single quotes in the generated YAML, like

```rb
command: 'copy-item -Recurse -Path z:\*.txt c:\windows\temp'
```

Comment: The first obvious question is **WHY??** -- wouldn't it be fine to just wrap the command in quotes before executing it, if that's your objective?

Comment: And not an exact answer to your question, but *maybe* `copy_propetries.to_yaml(canonical: true)` is what you want?

Comment: I am running puppet agent , for that in the yaml it should be present as --  command: 'copy-item -Recurse -Path z:*.txt c:\windows\temp'  otherwise I am getting error.

Comment: No it's not , i want the output to be in a yaml file as 'copy-item -Recurse -Path z:*.txt c:\windows\temp'   -- with in single quotes